# Blocks not working with nodejs and jade

Tags: node.js, pug, block

Reading for hours, I am pretty sure I understand how blocks in Jade work. Here is my `layout.jade` file:

```
!!! 5
html(lang="en")
  head
    title= title
    link(rel= 'stylesheet', href= '/style.css')
  body
    h1 Placeholder Title
    block content
```

And my index.jade file

```
extends layout
block content
  p Hello World
```

However, when I visit `index.jade` the only thing that shows up is

> "Placeholder Title"

The "content" block in `layout.jade` never gets replaced by the content block in `index.jade`

Comment: Assuming you are using jade directly (and not in express?), then when you `jade.compile` are you compiling `layout.jade` or `index.jade`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For blocks to work you need to do { layout: false }. More information can be found in the docs: https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#template-inheritance

Answer (score 2):

I don't see your route-handling code, but I assume you are doing:

```
res.render('layout')
```

instead of:

```
res.render('index')
```

You have to render index.jade (the file that `extends` the layout), and **not** layout.jade (which is like the "base class").